# selected objects in blender 2.83 question

Tags: modeling

so i downloaded blender 2.83 and after installing it i noticed something a little weird, i also downloaded BforArtists 2 and the exact same thing was present,when you select an object a double outline appears, i know in blender 2.82 this doesn't happen, i asked the same question on the BforArtists forum and the answer i got was that i need to upgrade my hardware in order to get the single outline back, which i find strange, my hardware isn't powerful enough so blender adds an extra outline and upgrading my hardware will bring it back down to a single outline, can anyone confirm that this is or isn't the case before i uninstall blender, the screenshot should show you what i'm talking about and why this makes 2.83 unusable.
[image]

Comment: If anything, it looks more like a graphics drivers issue. I know some users found solutions to a whole myriad of problems by updating their drivers (after updating to 2.83). Not saying it will solve it for sure, but it's a place to start - and in my opinion, far more likely than a hardware issue.

Comment: thanks Christopher, will update my drivers, answer is appreciated

Comment: FWIW, this bug popped up for me also when I upgraded to 2.83.  Related: https://developer.blender.org/T75826   

I'm running a 10 year old graphics card, so I might be out of luck.

Comment: well zippy youre not alone, i just looked at the drivers for my system and they are no longer being supported, i guess its going to be 2.82 till i can get a graphics card......i have a feeling that even though blender is free its going to get quite costly

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do with the software, 2.82 is and will remain a very good choice as a free software. The improvements in the newer versions are anyway mainly focused on the capabilites of newer hardware so you wouldn't benefit from it with an older machine. 2.79 is still used by a lot of people !

Comment: [![2.83 object selection doubled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50zzR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50zzR.png) For those who trying to find solution of double lines of selected object in Blender 2.83. I will use 2.82 until I buy new PC...